# Encrypt file Line by Line in Python using RSA and Compare it to another File

Tags: python, linux, encryption, rsa

On my Linux Debian server, using python, I am trying to read a file of names line-by-line and encrypt it using the public RSA. Then I want to compare the encrypted line to another file that I have, which is also encrypted. If they are equal to each other I would like to print out the name in the decrypted and encrypted form. I have never used python before, so any help would be much appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
key = RSA.generate(2048)

names = open('names.txt')
cipher = open('ciphertext.txt',"r")

readname = names.readline()
readcipher = cipher.readlines()

while readname:
    enc_name = pubkey.encrypt(names,0)
    if enc_name == readcipher:
         print readname
         readname = names.readline()
names.close()
cipher.close()
```

Comment: Why are you using RSA, do you need different encrypt and decrypt keys? Note that the size of the data you can encrypt is limited to slightly less than the key size. Data is usually encrypted with a symmetric key algorithm such as AES.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your actual question is but maybe this will help?

```
 for name_plaintext,name_encoded in zip(names,cipher):
     if do_encode(name_plaintext) == name_encoded:
        print name_decoded,"==>",name_encoded
```